# % Difference Pivot Table python

Tags: python, pivot-table

I have a sample dataframe/table as below and I would like to do a simple pivot table in Python to calculate the % difference from the previous year.

```
DataFrame
Year Month Count Amount Retailer
2019  5      10    100    ABC
2019  3      8     80    XYZ
2020  3      8     80    ABC
2020  5      7     70    XYZ
...
```

Expected Output

```
    MONTH   %Diff 
ABC  7       -0.2
XYG  8       -0.125
```

Thanks,

EDIT: *I would like to reiterate that I would like to create the following table below. Not to do a join with the two tables*

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a `groupby` not `pivot`

`gdf = df.groupby(['Retailer']).agg({'Amount': 'pct_change'})`

Then rename and merge with original df

`df = gdf.rename(columns={'Amount': '%Diff'}).dropna().merge(df, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)`

```
   %Diff  Year  Month  Count  Amount Retailer
2 -0.200  2020      3      7      80      ABC
3 -0.125  2020      5      8      70      XYZ
```